# Hadoop in renaming files

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs

Is there a simple command for hadoop that can change the name of a file (in the HDFS) from its old name to a new name?

Comment: The answer WORKS, why didn't you accept?

Answer (score 53):

Use the following :

```
hadoop fs -mv oldname newname
```

Answer (score 3):

The above ones works pretty well. Also this version works all the time for me.

```
hdfs dfs -mv oldname.txt newname.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write below query to change the name of the file in both environment Local and HDFS environment.

Local machine : mv 'Old file name along with path' 'new file name along with path'

e.g: Xyz.txt is the file present under user folder which you want to rename to new_xyz.txt

**mv 'user/Xyz.txt' 'user/new_xyz.txt';**

Hadoop environment (HDFS environment) : let's say you have already dumped the file in HDFS environment under folder (for e.g.) **test/Xyz.txt**

syntax could be : hadoop fs -mv 'old file with path' ' New file name with path'

**hadoop fs -mv 'test/Xyz.txt' 'test/new_xyz.txt'**